# Is right and how to to remove classes from a React application using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

In React Native(and so React), using Redux, we have the "limitation" that we should not store unserializable data, so every single class instance become a plain object.
So, I think that doesn't make anymore sense to use Classes.

For example, if my application is a car fleet management app, probably I'lll have some entities like `Car`, `User`, etc

Now my question is, where would you manage and instance creation?
In the classic OOP I simply do `new Car();`, but in this case, maybe, the "right way" should be to `dispatch` the action creator the will do required operation, so `dispatch(makeCar())`, is this right?

And what if I've some calculated property, like `get age`?

I'm pretty new to this world...

Comment: Imagine the redux store to be a database. It should only contain the plain data. If you want to create domain objects from that you would need a tool that can instanciate them given the data from your store or write them to the store as plain data given the domain object.

Comment: Or in other words you would need an ORM, for example there is [`redux-orm`](https://redux-orm.github.io/redux-orm/) but it might not fit your use case or existing code.

Comment: @trixn so it would be correct to have classes and simply:
1-create new instance with the class constructor; 
2-serialize any object inside the action that store it in the redux store; 
3-execute again the constructor when we retrieve an instance from the redux store; 

???

Comment: Yes roughly speaking that would be needed. But there are other operations like updating an already instanciated domain object. Creating a wrapper around redux that manages creates, updates and deletes of domain objects is a non-trivial task. You can have a look at `redux-orm` to see how they handle it. But it is a fair amount of overhead that comes with that kind of OOP style. Redux is likely not the best fit for that.

Comment: Also see this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43721911/5005177